# What is this component? Car AC control unit ring encoder

Tags: potentiometer, rotary-encoder

So my mode door knob (the one to direct air to windshield, feet, etc.) has gone bad, it always blows air to the windshield. I tore down the dashboard and got to the problem, the potentiometer-like component seems to have rusted, presumably from some water getting to it.
I have searched all over the internet for this component with no luck.

Would someone know how to find it? Or what other similar component could replace it?

What I know:
Ring encoder
14 or 12 position
Text on part: B 14 1503 OA.MAL
5 pins

This is as close as I have come:
https://www.mouser.mx/c/electromechanical/encoders/?mounting%20style=PCB%20Mount&shaft%20type=Ring

In terms of fixing the part, it seems to always think it is in the last position, could it be that the wiper has a bad connection due to the rust? Would this be fixable?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would think it is a custom part built specifically for this specific car make, because it is an element of the design (the knob itself). You could probably source the whole assembly, either OEM or aftermarket though.

Comment: What vehicle is this from?

Comment: @Bryan This is for a 2017 RAM ProMaster. Yeah, I found the whole assembly but it is rather expensive, the thing seems to be a complicated computer. I am the kind of guy that tries to fix stuff before changing the whole thing, might be hard this time though.

Comment: @ManuelRuiz dodge probably uses this part in a lot of hvac control assemblies - I asked because it looks like what I expect my grand caravan to have inside. I recommend heading to a wrecking yard and pulling a similar looking assembly from any dodge vehicle.